# Es6 TypeScript arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Решил побаловаться TypeScript и es6, а в частности Proxy.

Проблема в том, что в отладчике (Edge) показывется и содержимое и длина arguments, 
а вот в коде все [методы преобразования в массив](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)  возвращается []
или обращения к длине возвращает 0.

```
  class Item {
    constructor(public resolve: any, public value: any) { };
}


class CounterComponent {
    public currentCount: any;
    private dictionary = {};
    private proxy: any;
     constructor() { this.SetProxy(); }
    private SetProxy(): void {

        this.proxy = new Proxy({}, {

            get: (rcvr, name) => {

                return () => {

                    let args: Array<any> = [];
                    let length = arguments.length; //length==0
                    let args1 = [...arguments];    //args1==[]
                    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                        args.push(arguments[i]);

                    }

                    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        //  resolve(123);
                        let item = new Item(resolve, args);
                        this.dictionary[name] = item;

                    });


                    return promise;

                };

            }


        });
    }
    public async CallMethodAsync() {


        this.currentCount = await this.proxy.AllHello("Всем Привет");
    }

    public setResult(): void {

        let key: string;
        for (let name in this.dictionary) {
            key = name;

        }

        let item = <Item>this.dictionary[key];
        item.resolve(item.value);

    }
}
```

При этом await отрабатывает.
И еще есть ли аналог C# финализатор, что бы понять когда объект подвергается сборке мусора.

Comment: у стрелочных функций нет arguments, то есть в твоем случае ты получаешь arguments от `SetProxy`

Comment: _И еще есть ли аналог C# финализатор, что бы понять когда объект подвергается сборке мусора._ - нет.

Comment: В ES6 есть и главное, что в отладчике то ((Edge) показывает содержимое

Comment: На какой из двух комментариев ты ответил?

Comment: @ Grundy спасибо, а как выкрутиться в первом и втором случае? Вот здесь http://soft.vub.ac.be/~tvcutsem/proxies/ arguments типа получают

Comment: Я про стрелочные функции. В отладчике arguments видны

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51595/discussion-between-grundy-and-serginio).

Comment: Да вызывается как this.currentCount = await this.proxy.AllHello("Всем Привет");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что одно из ограничений [стрелочных функций](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> #### [Не имеет собственного объекта arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#%D0%9D%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0_arguments)
>
> Стрелочные функции не имеют собственного объекта *arguments*, поэтому в теле стрелочных функций *arguments* будет ссылаться на переменную в окружающей области.

---

Самое простое решение - использовать **не** стрелочную функцию, например

```
get: (rcvr, name) => {
    return function() {
        let args: Array<any> = [];
        ...
    }
}
```

Альтернативное решение: использовать [rest-параметры](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters)

```
get: (rcvr, name) => {
    return (...args)=>{
        ...
    }
}
```

В этом случае `args` уже массив и с ним можно работать сразу без дополнительных операций.

Comment: Спасибо сейчас проверю

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!